# Changing selection in a select with the Chosen plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to change the currently selected option in a select with the Chosen plugin.

The [documentation](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) covers updating the list, and triggering an event when an option is selected, but nothing (that I can see) on externally changing the currently selected value.

I have made a [jsFiddle to demonstrate the code](http://jsfiddle.net/gakman/queZ6/) and my attempted ways of changing the selection:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('select').val(2);
    $('select').chosen().val(2);
    $('select').chosen().select(2);
});
```

Comment: I couldn't run the jsfiddle demonstration you provided. could you please update it.

Comment: Okay. The reason I couldn't run your demonstration was the chosen library was pointing to an incorrect url. Here's the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/queZ6/666/)

Answer (score 238, accepted):

From the "Updating Chosen Dynamically" section in the [docs](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/):  You need to trigger the 'chosen:updated' event on the field

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('select').chosen();

    $('button').click(function() {
        $('select').val(2);
        $('select').trigger("chosen:updated");
    });

});
```

NOTE: versions prior to 1.0 used the following:

```
$('select').trigger("liszt:updated");
```

Comment: FYI: they've updated to 1.0 which now uses `chosen:updated` instead of `liszt:updated`

Comment: I stumbled here as I was trying to find a way to select the best currently matching option from a multi select chosen search result list (whenever focus was lost). Here's [a short fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zFBCy/4/) about my explorations. You don't event need to trigger any events. Perhaps, it is of use for someone else too... :)

Comment: despite that the above code works,this happens only once.I mean if I click again menu where chosen plugin is attached does not take the value which is inside val().Why this might be happening

Comment: I don't get how this get

Comment: I don't get how this get's you your value.

Comment: I know this is an old post - but a simpler way to update is just in one string:  `$('select').val(2).trigger("chosen:updated");`

Comment: mentioning `liszt:updated` is important. thx. `chosen:updated` doesn't work on the version of chosen we have, which is used by a wordpress plugin we use - it needs upgrading, but wordpress upgrades on big sites require a lot of planning!

Comment: @Lucas Welper: you should also change `$('select').val(2);` into `$('select').val(2).change();`, because changing the selected option of a select with jQuery doesn't trigger the change event and some people might need it.

Answer (score 51):

My answer is late, but i want to add some information that is missed in all above answers.

1) If you want to select single value in chosen select.

```
$('#select-id').val("22").trigger('chosen:updated');
```

2) If you are using multiple chosen select, then may you need to set multiple values at single time.

```
$('#documents').val(["22", "25", "27"]).trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Information gathered from following links:
1) [Chosen Docs](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)
2) [Chosen Github Discussion](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/605)

Comment: Noting that "22","25" etc.. are the values, not the inner HTML, for instance <option value="25">sometext</option>

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you have to remove the current options in order to manipulate the selected options.

Here is an example how to set options:

```
<select id="mySelectId" class="chosen-select" multiple="multiple">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
  <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
  <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
  <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
  <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
</select>

<script>
activateChosen($('body'));
selectChosenOptions($('#mySelectId'), ['Argentina', 'Germany']);

function activateChosen($container, param) {
    param = param || {};
    $container.find('.chosen-select:visible').chosen(param);
    $container.find('.chosen-select').trigger("chosen:updated");
}

function selectChosenOptions($select, values) {
    $select.val(null);                                  //delete current options
    $select.val(values);                                //add new options
    $select.trigger('chosen:updated');
}
</script>
```

JSFiddle (including howto append options):
https://jsfiddle.net/59x3m6op/1/

Comment: To account for the case where the select has no value yet, update `var selected = mySelect.val();` to `var selected = mySelect.val() || [];` instead.

Comment: ...or if you have an ancient version use: $select.trigger('liszt:updated');

Answer (score 1):

In case of **multiple** type of select and/or if you want to remove already selected items one by one, directly within a dropdown list items, you can use something like:

```
jQuery("body").on("click", ".result-selected", function() {
    var locID = jQuery(this).attr('class').split('__').pop();
    // I have a class name: class="result-selected locvalue__209"
    var arrayCurrent = jQuery('#searchlocation').val();
    var index = arrayCurrent.indexOf(locID);
    if (index > -1) {
        arrayCurrent.splice(index, 1);
    }
    jQuery('#searchlocation').val(arrayCurrent).trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```