# Change the value of Chosen.js select box using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the value of my select box which has [Chosen.js](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) overlay. The idea is to change the selected value when user clicks a button.

With regular select box I can change the value by doing:

```
$('#GroupsShowNext').unbind("click").click(function() {
    var index = $("#GroupsViewGroups").prop("selectedIndex");
    index += 1;

    $('#GroupsViewGroups option').eq(index).attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('#GroupsViewGroups').change();
});
```

But with Chosen.js it doesn't work anymore..I have tried few things but nothing has worked. Any ideas how to get it work?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55zJ6/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing selection in a select with the Chosen plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980131/changing-selection-in-a-select-with-the-chosen-plugin)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So after posting this question I continued trying to solve this problem and happened to found out a way to do this.

```
$('#GroupsShowNext').unbind("click").click(function() {
    var index = $("#GroupsViewGroups").prop("selectedIndex");
    index += 1;
    $('#GroupsViewGroups option').eq(index).attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('#GroupsViewGroups').chosen().change();
    $("#GroupsViewGroups").trigger("liszt:updated");
});
```

The key was to put .chosen() before .change() and then trigger "liszt:updated". It works but I don't know if this is the best way to do this..

If you have a better way to do this, please let me know

Comment: you can also see @LuizCarlosLucena answer about also being able to use "chosen:update"

Comment: chosen:update is used in the latest version, for legecy versions use liszt:updated

Answer (score 8):

I stumbled across this trying to figure it out myself.

I was able to do it with a combination of changing the selected index on the original field, and then triggering the `liszt:updated` event on that field:

```
$('#GroupsViewGroups')[0].selectedIndex = $('#GroupsViewGroups')[0].selectedIndex + 1;
$('#GroupsViewGroups').trigger('liszt:updated');
```

Answer (score 5):

Just an update (I found this page from google, maybe other people will find it also)

I've tryed to comment the @splitz's answer but I couldn't because I still don't have enough reputation.

The new way to do it is:

```
$('#GroupsShowNext').unbind("click").click(function() {
    var index = $("#GroupsViewGroups").prop("selectedIndex");
    index += 1;
    $('#GroupsViewGroups option').eq(index).attr('selected', 'selected');
    $("#GroupsViewGroups").trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

Now, the trick is the "chosen:updated".

Updated answer found on: [Changing selection in a select with the Chosen plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980131/changing-selection-in-a-select-with-the-chosen-plugin)

Answer (score 2):

With the plugin Chosen.js it works.

```
var myIndex = 4;

$("select#GroupsViewGroups").prop('selectedIndex', myIndex);
```