# jquery: switch chosen selectbox selected value on click

Tags: jquery

i want to interchange the value from one selectbox to another using jquery,

MY selectbox is in the form of http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Example:

say i have 2 dropdown selectbox,in first i have selected USD & on second i have selected EURO  , on click of switch button both the selectbox selected value & level should interchange

http://jsfiddle.net/34kcb/  (without chosen effect, works fine)

I tried below code but its now giving me what i am looking for, so may be you can help me

```
$("body").on("click", "#switchid", function(){ 
               var frm='';var to='';
               frm=$("#from_currency option:selected").val(); 
               to=$("#to_currency option:selected").val(); 
               $("#to_currency").val(frm);
              $("#from_currency").val(to);
              //currencyConverter();
  });
```

**HTML code**

```
 <select name="from_currency" id="from_currency">
                  <option value="USD">USD : United States Dollar</option> 
                  <option value="EUR">EUR : Euro</option> 
                  <option value="JPY">JPY : Japanese Yen</option>
                  <option value="INR">INR : Indian Rupee</option>
     </select>
<br/>

    <select name="to_currency" id="to_currency"> 
                  <option value="EUR">EUR : Euro</option>  
                  <option value="USD">USD : United States Dollar</option> 
                  <option value="JPY">JPY : Japanese Yen</option>
                  <option value="INR">INR : Indian Rupee</option>
     </select>

<br/>

<input type="button" id="switchid" value="Switch"/>
```

## UPDATE:

In simple selectbox its working but after integrating with [Choosen selectbox](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)  ,same thing is 
not working . any idea?

Comment: Your fiddle works exactly how you explain it should

Comment: i solve my issue from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9679013/2178632

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
$("#switchid").on("click", function(){ 
          var frm = '';
          var to ='';
          frm = $("#from_currency").val(); 
          to = $("#to_currency option:selected").val(); 
          $("#to_currency").val(frm);
          $("#from_currency").val(to);
          $("#from_currency, #to_currency").trigger("chosen:updated");
        });
```

The last line `" $("#from_currency, #to_currency").trigger("chosen:updated");"` should trigger chosen to update. I haven't tested this though, as I don't have chosen (or time at the moment)! :)

Comment: plz check my question once again, i have diffrent type of selectbox

Comment: trigger this function end of the above function $("#from_currency, #to_currency").trigger("chosen:updated");

Comment: i tried what you have give but still nothing happening

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("body").on("click", "#switchid", function(){ 
  var frm = '';
  var to ='';
  frm = $("#from_currency").val(); 
  to = $("#to_currency").val(); 
  $("#to_currency").val(frm);
  $("#from_currency").val(to);
  $("#from_currency, #to_currency").trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/H5x5u/

You don't need to select the option:selected, the .val() jQuery does that for you.

Comment: The problem is the dropdown is hidden when you're using the chosenbox. You'll want to add $("#to_currency, #from_currency").trigger("chosen:updated"); just before the end of the line. I've updated my answer, it *should* work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on("click", "#switchid", function(){ 
 var firstDropDownValue = $("#from_currency option:selected").attr('selected','selected').val();  
 var secondDropDownValue = $("#to_currency option:selected").attr('selected','selected').val();
var afterSwitchFirstValue = $("#from_currency").val(secondDropDownValue);        
var afterSwitchSecondValue = $("#to_currency").val(firstDropDownValue);
  });
```

pl chk the answer in http://jsfiddle.net/34kcb/2/ and the value is interchanging in selectbox its working as you need..